# Intermittent multi-threading in Grass 7?

Tags: grass-gis

I have a script with runs GRASS 7 r.li.* commands through R with spgrass6 on Ubuntu 14.04/64 bits. I ran the script and was amazed at the speed at which it was running. So, I looked at the system monitor and was pleasantly surprised to see that the load was nicely shared among the 4 cores. I later ran the same script again, on the same file, after rebooting the computer, and everything was running much slower. I examined the system monitor and now everything was now single-threaded. The same functions now run at 1/10 of the original speed.

What could have caused GRASS to go from multi-threading to single-threading. How do I revert it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The r.li suite has been completely rewritten. While in the past it ran in parallel mode, the results were not reliable. The only way was to rewrite it from scratch at the expense of the multi-core approach.

Please try a recent (i.e. less than 1 week) SVN snapshot of GRASS GIS 7 to use the now working version of r.li.

Comment: Thanks for this. In what ways are the results from previous r.li versions not reliable? The difficulty I have is that r.li functions in GRASS 7 take about 50x time to run so my current analysis would take more than a week to complete, versus 2.5 hours in GRASS 6.4.

Comment: It has also been updated in GRASS GIS 6.4.4. See http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/6.4.4-News#Majormodulechanges . I understand that the loss of parallelism is annoying but at least you get results which are comparable to Fragstats, other software, and manual computation. Before this was not necessarily the case and sometimes the results got corrupted (AFAIK broken memory management in r.li which is got fixed). In GRASS GIS we insist on quality, i.e. correct results and reliable computations!

Comment: I just did a comparison of Grass 6.4.3 indices and those of 7. Most indices are strongly correlated between versions, although the units are quite different. However, "shape" and "pielou" give entirely different results.

Comment: You don't need to trust my answers but we spent months on bugfixing the code. There was a reason for it.

Comment: Don't worry, I trust your answers. I was just curious to see the different. Thanks for your good work!

Comment: Thanks! BTW: we have developed a small test case which known results which could be used also for other software. It will be shipping soon with the source code.